# A generic predicate which can be customized by caller?

Tags: c#, functional-programming, delegates, predicate

I have a bunch of Predicates defined like this, each checking for a different http status code:

```
readonly Predicate<HttpResponseData> createdHttpStatusPredicate = (HttpResponseData responseData) => {
    return responseData.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created;
};

readonly Predicate<HttpResponseData> okHttpStatusPredicate = (HttpResponseData responseData) => {
    return responseData.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
};

...
```

I'm passing them into the following method like this (code has been simplified a little to cut out irrelevant details):

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseData> HttpCaller(HttpMethod requestMethod, Predicate<HttpResponseData> predicate)
{
    HttpResponseData response = await SendHttpRequest(requestMethod);

    if (predicate(response) == true)
        return response;
    else
        return null;
}
```

Here is a sample call sending one predicate into above method:

```
HttpResponseData data = await HttpRequestUtils.HttpCaller(HttpMethod.Post, createdHttpStatusPredicate);
```

I'm wondering, can I combine all the predicates in some generic predicate, or perhaps somehow specify the http status to look for into the predicate when I'm calling `HttpCaller` ?

Yes, I know the above example doesn't make much sense as I can just pass the http status I'm looking for into `HttpCaller` directly without going through a predicate, but in my case `HttpCaller` can receive my complex predicates as inputs too, based on where `HttpCaller` is being called from

Comment: If I've understood the problem correctly, you have two cases: **1.** `HttpCaller` is called with `Predicate` that checks only `HttpStatus`; **2.** `HttpCaller` is called with complex `Predicate`. Am I correct? If I am, why not use two methods `HttpCaller`: one with expected `HttpStatus` arg, and the other - with `Predicate` arg?

Comment: So the HttpCaller method handles many different scenarios and so accepts a number of different predicates, SOME of which only test for a specific http status .... So it doesn't make sense to have multiple methods do the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next two approaches can be used to get rid of all the predicates that only check for `HttpStatusCode`.

---

### 1. Create a method that creates a `Predicate` for a given `HttpStatusCode`:

```
public static Predicate<HttpResponseData> CreatePredicateByHttpStatusCode(HttpStatusCode status)
{
    return r => r.StatusCode == status;
}
```

And then use this method when you need a `Predicate` that only checks for a given `HttpStatusCode`:

```
var result = await HttpCaller(httpMethod, CreatePredicateByHttpStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK));
```

---

### 2. Create an overload of the method `HttpCaller` that accepts `HttpStatusCode` and only checks for a given `HttpStatusCode`:

```
// This is your current method. It accepts a common Predicate that is used
// to check for complex conditions.
public static async Task<HttpResponseData> HttpCaller(HttpMethod requestMethod, Predicate<HttpResponseData> predicate)
{
    HttpResponseData response = await SendHttpRequest(requestMethod);

    if (predicate(response) == true)
        return response;
    else
        return null;
}

// This is a new Method. It accepts HttpStatusCode instead of the Predicate.
// It can be used for checking only for HttpStatusCode.
public static async Task<HttpResponseData> HttpCaller(HttpMethod requestMethod, HttpStatusCode status)
{
    // Here your original method HttpCaller is used.
    return await HttpCaller(requestMethod, r => r.StatusCode == status);
}
```

Overloaded form of the `HttpCaller` can be used when you need to check only for `HttpStatusCode`:

```
var result = await HttpCaller(httpMethod, HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

Comment: Your first solution is awesome, however it can be further cut down ... Where you're calling `CreatePredicateByHttpStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK)`, just replace it with `r => r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK` and then you don't even need the `CreatePredicateByHttpStatusCode()` method :)